# Filling a SplitContainer with a TreeView while Dock is set to Fill

Tags: vb.net

If I have a new project with a User Control and a MDI with a 2 window Split Container. One on the left an done on the right. Then If I create a new User Control as follows

```
Public Class
    Private Sub TreeView()
        Dim pbTreeView As Forms.TreeView
        pbTreeView = New Forms.TreeView()

        Me.Controls.Add(pbTreeView)
        pbTreeView.Nodes.Clear()

        Dim root = New TreeNode("Price Book")
        pbTreeView.Nodes.Add(root)
        pbTreeView.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Settings"))
        pbTreeView.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Sales"))
        pbTreeView.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Pricing"))
    End Sub
End Class

    Private Sub TreeViewControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TreeView()
    End Sub
```

I put this User Control in the Left panel of the split container and set the dock to Fill. When I run it. the dock itself is filled properly. but the border and the actual TreeView is NOT made to fit the entirety of the UC in the left container. How can I go about fitting it in there. With the actual data, it will be long enough to even need a horizontal scroll while the data from the selected node will populate the right panel of the spit container(haven't tackled this bit yet).

Comment: Nothing in your posted code does a Dock.Fill.

Comment: Hard to answer correctly when you don't explain why you created a UC.  Looks to me that it contains only one control, the tree view.  In which case you simply set the pbTreeView.Dock to fill as well.  And in which case you must not use a UC, instead derive your own class from TreeView.  Very important technique, it tends to have to be learned since the design view isn't very useful on such a class.